# Can I stop Hyper-V from the command line without powershell?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-command-prompt

I have Hyper-V and one VM running on a dedicated server at 1and1.com. I did not realize it was against their policy to "spoof mac addresses" which is apparently what Hyper-V does when you boot up a VM with bridged networking.

My server has been kicked off their switch and I can access it only through a remote server console (via serial port), which gives me access to CMD. I do not have access to powershell, the windows GUI, and I cannot download or install anything.

Which services can I stop to assure the VM stops running (It's okay if it doesn't shutdown safely) so that I can request being re-attached to their LAN?

If it helps, this is Windows Server 2012 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch PowerShell from any command prompt:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Comment: There is nothing in the WindowsPowerShell folder. Luckily (wherever it actually is) it was in the path so just typing PowerShell at the command prompt worked. I could then use `Get-VM` to list the VMs, `Stop-VM` to stop the offender, and finally `Get-VM` again to confirm it was stopped!